# Understand threading in Reactor / Webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I created this implementation in my Controller which works totally fine so far in test and in production.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Mono<LanguageResultDto> addEntry(Flux<String> body,
                                        String languageId,
                                        String fileName) {
    return vaultRepository.findByDatasetId(languageId)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                KeyVault keyVault = KeyVault.of(languageId);
                return vaultRepository.save(keyVault);
            }))
            .map(keyVault -> translatorService.createTranslator(languageId))
            .map(translator -> body.map(translator::update) // can have a short spike in load (CPU) or time (processing)
                    .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()))
            .flatMap(flux -> storageService.addEntry(flux, languageId, fileName));
}
```

As more I read about Reactor and its Thread model like [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#threading-model) as more I get confused.

> The schedulers have names that suggest a specific concurrency
> strategy — for example, “parallel” (for CPU-bound work with a limited
> number of threads) or “elastic” (for I/O-bound work with a large
> number of threads). If you see such threads, it means some code is
> using a specific thread pool Scheduler strategy.

As commented in my code `translator::update` can cause spikes in the CPU load or just take a bit longer to process. As I understand from the docu in such a case I should use then `Schedulers.parallel()` is that right?

Regarding this I have already 2 questions.

1. Is it important to add `.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()))` to
   `body.map(translator::update)` or could I add it already anywhere
   else before or later like `.findByDatasetId(datasetId)` or `.flatMap(flux -> storageService.addEntry(flux, languageId, fileName))`
   Please explain why
2. If I don't add it at all and I have a machine with 4 CPU cores and
   no Hyperthreading or similar I understand from the docu that only 4
   threads are available to process requests

   ```
   > you can expect one thread for the server and several others for
   > request processing (typically as many as the number of CPU cores)
   ```

   So what happens when my microservices is requested by more than 4
   users and it comes to the very rare case that the first four users
   requests require longer time to execute at the same time, what will happen to the 4+n
   requests? Will Spring create new Threads on the fly and kill them too after?

Moreover I have another question in that context.

`storageService.addEntry(flux, languageId, fileName)`

the storageService impl. makes a call to another microservices B (all reactive with WebClient)

B itself writes to a disk, so it's I/O bound.

From the docu I understand that service B should make use within its implementation of `.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());`

My question here is do I need to add this to my implementation above too, like this?

```
     .flatMap(flux -> storageService.addEntry(flux, languageId, fileName)
                      .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());;
```

And how does that work if I had to add `.publishOn(Schedulers.parallel()))` somewhere before or after?

I hope my question are clear since I am very lost with these concepts of parallel/boundesElastic combined and distributed over another microservice.

I'll appreciate context to your answer by a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding the `publishOn` - I don't think you need it in your case, because the actual execution happens before that point. You need the `subscribeOn` there

Comment: For the CPU and threads. If your task is a CPU bound then it doesn't makes sense to run more threads than CPUs, because hardware is busy and a new task would just wait in the queue consuming memory. For IO it's a different story because you can switch the thread (i.e., the CPU) to another task until this one waits for IO (i.e, data transfer).